# Listen for URL fragment id change in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

It seems that the WebViewClient methods such as shouldInterceptRequest(), onPageStarted(), and shouldOverrideUrlLoading() only listen for URL changes that cause the WebView to load a new page. Is there a way to detect URL changes for fragment IDs, i.e. index.html#fragment_id, on a WebView?

Comment: Use JavascriptInterface of webview and window hashChange event in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mitvenkatesan described in his comment to the question, this can be achieved by overriding the window.onhashchange() event of the page inside the WebView.

It turns out that this solution has already been addressed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18445563/3761521).

Answer (score 11):

I know that this is a really old question but i found out a solution that isn't available anywhere in Stack Overflow. jpetitto's answer works but it messes up javascript if we use hash change for routing or other such features.

I found out that by overriding the method `doUpdateVisitedHistory` in `WebViewClient` we can catch url's on hash change. Do see below snippet for example.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url, boolean isReload) {
            super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
            // somecode to run on hash change.
        }

}
```

Note: this method is fired on hash change and url change.

Comment: From someone that has been searching all afternoon: Thank you.

Comment: This is excellent, it will detect the url change. But can you suggest how to navigate to the pages in SPA without reloading the page. I am searching, but couldn't get any hint. Thanks

Comment: I believe you want to have path routing instead of hash routing without the page reload. In that case you can use history api. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History