# WebViewClient onPageStarted never gets triggered browsing SPA

Tags: android, angularjs, android-webview

I'm opening in a WebView a SPA written in angularjs which uses hashbang urls. (e.g. http://www.myapp.com/#!/page1) I can only see onPageFinished getting triggered and never onPageStarted.

Is there any issue with navigating hashbang urls in a single page application?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String, android.graphics.Bitmap) Have a look on this.

Comment: Yes, I've read the API docs, I was wondering if there's an alternative way to intercept the url before the page starts loading.

Comment: what is your use case? do you need any task in onPageStarted() that you do not want when onPageFinished() load?

Comment: I want to intercept some specific navigation events and, instead of performing the standard navigation I want to perform other actions. for instance I want to intercept http://www.myapp.com/#!/login and, instead I want to display a native login page

Comment: I've found 2 possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176519/android-webview-is-it-possible-to-detect-url-hash-change/18445563#18445563 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555616/listen-for-url-fragment-id-change-in-webview

Comment: share your code