# Does android WebView support <a> tags with download attribute? is there any workaround?

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-download-manager

I'so I have an Android app that loads a WebView containing `<a>` tags like this

```
<a id="download-7630" href="/files/download/7630" download>someFilename.anyExtension</a>
```

In the context of the app's back end the files get served by a java controller connecting to mongoDB. I can't change the server code so I need a workaround for this. they are GET requests GET that return

```
ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=someFilename.anyExtension")
            .contentLength(file.getLength())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(file.getContentType()))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(file.getInputStream()));
```

The problem I'm having is that this download tags work perfectly on the browser and console says for example: "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "https://XYZDOMAIN/files/download/22306"." but when I click them from the WebView none of the events get fired up.

**I have debug points in** the WebViewClient's `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), onLoadResource(), onPageStarted() and shouldInterceptRequest()` and **I get NOTHING**, its like somehow the click or touch event is being ignored just for the tags formed like this, everything else in the app works fine in the WebView.
*(debug points work fine for example when loading the site that contains the links, or when navigating between pages in the site)*

my webView settings include:

```
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
            webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
            webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
MyWebViewClient myWebViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(myWebViewClient);
```

MyWebViewClient is just a class that extends WebViewClient where I'm overriding the methods I'm trying to debug

What I'm trying to do is to manage the files the server sends back to start an intent offering the user to open the file, but my problem is that I haven't been able to intercept anything to even try and do that.

I've read solutions to handle the download in AsyncTasks or adding DownloadListeners and stuff like that but my problem is that I haven't been able to intercept the click on those links (html tags).

Any ideas of what might be wrong or missing?

Comment: Forgive me, but in which way is this question related to HTML5 or MongoDB? It's rather an Android permission thingy, right?

Comment: You might be right about mongoDB, but since download attribute is html5 might be an issue between that and the WebView that I don't know about so my bad, I changed the tags... :/

Comment: Please add more answers mindeh's one is not valid

Comment: @Elkdor have you tried mWebView.onDownloadListener() ?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but still was not working. The only thing I have managed to do to make it work was mocking the same links and removing the html5 "download" attribute entirely then I can apply either the onDownloadListener or the answer by mindeh. 

However since I need to make it work on tags with that attribute on the html I haven't marked any solution. I just think is not supported at all or a tags with that attribute get ignored on touch events.

Comment: Webview has a bug preventing the anchor link to fire action if the download attribute is present. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198532

Answer (score 2):

Some people reported a WebView bug in the past, so there could be versions of android which does not support download attribute with the "a" tag.
Newer versions WebView can handle the download attribute, however.

code from this post:[Download file inside WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069050/download-file-inside-webview)  does the job.

```
wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Name of your downloadble file goes here, example: Mathematics II ");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

A click on, for instance, `<a href="example.com.file" download></a>` does not fire WebViewClient::onLoadResource.
I get the rational but seems like a very unjavascript sort of behavior...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening on the browser:

1. User clicks link (pointing to a file)
2. Browser gets HTTP headers for that URL / link, they say "it's an attachment"
3. Browser / download manager handles it as smth to be downloaded rather than redirected to

Webview probably doesn't know how to handle downloads, doesn't know how to display a content with such Content-Type header and does nothing.

What you could do is:

1. Intercept redirect in a webview (it should still happen, event if webview doesn't display anything when it understands it cannot)
2. You'll get a URL
3. Recognise it as one which points to a file (for instance, with a RegExp)
4. Handle file download outside the webview

To intercept redirect URL you need to:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // Check the URL here - if it is a file, 
            // then initiate the download
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mindeh, I have actually tried that but the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() never gets called for this links I know the method works because it does get fired for everything else.

Comment: I'm sorry if i was not too clear... what I meant when I said I get nothing. I mean that none of the debug points stop an any of the methods mentioned when I click the link so I haven't been able to intercept it like you suggest.

Comment: Im guessing it might be issue with href being a relative link but I can't seem to find a possible workaround

Comment: You could also try similar trick as is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176519/android-webview-is-it-possible-to-detect-url-hash-change I.e. detect window location change in JavaScript and then call your Java code